# How to use python request module to download image in website that need to trigger a button to show the url

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am currently working on a python script that can help to display Manga images from a website.
While I can successfully getting Image URL from the website, there are some special cases that require a button click to show URL in HTML (to change button display in the same page).
Here is an example webpage.

http://www.dm5.com/manhua-shirendixiacheng/

When I try to look at the HTML code of that button (with string "请点击此处继续阅读！"), 
there is only a `href="javascript:void();"` in the button element, which I don't understand how it works and what kind of parameter it change when I manually click on it
(otherwise maybe i can try to send some parameter while using request in python ?)

I hope that someone can tell me the method of getting the Manga Chapter URL from this page through python request module.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a web browser automation tool, like [splinter](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter) using a headless browser.

With this approach you can just find and press the button and then look for the URL

Otherwise you will need to discover the logic behind that button.

Comment: But i want to avoid using web browser automation to remain the speed of script. Also, once we click the button, we don't need to click again. So i think the website store and check a parameter. Thank you.